# A zip file link is not getting downloaded, but copying the url and pasting to browser works

Tags: html, jenkins

I have a html report, which I am opening in Jenkins HTML. It has a zip URL, so in that report if I click the link, it opens a new tab and gets closed. Its not downloading the file.

But if I copy the link URL and paste in another tab, its getting downloaded.

```
<td width="50%"><a href="http://sample-qa--ap-northeast-1-test-reports.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/1711029600000/84/jp/regression/files/regression.zip" target="_blank">Cucumber Report Download Link</a></td>
```

This is the HTML code. Can anyone tell whats the issue